# Azure ML Studio- Container has crashed. Did your init method fail

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy an ML model through the Azure ML Studio using the notebook itself. The commands we are using can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where?tabs=python#define-an-inference-configuration

We have registered the model as below-

```
from azureml.core.model import Model
model = Model.register(ws, model_name="pdmrfull", model_path="pdmrfull.model")
```

But while running this command-

```
service = Model.deploy(
    ws,
    "myservice",
    ["pdmrfull.model"],
    dummy_inference_config,
    deployment_config,
    overwrite=True,
)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

We are getting the error that `container has crashed. Did your init method fail?`

```
  File "/var/azureml-app/pdmscore.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

The `init` method is-

```
def init():
    pipeline = PipelineModel.load('pdmrfull.model')
```

Answer (score 1):

The logs are pretty explanatory, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'`. What are all the dependencies that you installed in the deploy configuration(environment)?. Check that, maybe you didn't install `pyspark`.